# Modbus over python3 on Raspberry Pi, is producing a usbserial error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pymodbus

I'm wondering if any can help explain the error I get below wrt to my serial port.

I'm using a USB-to-RS485 cord to connect to an epever solar controller.  I have a small python3 program to read the registers out over Modbus.  I have it working successfully over Windows with Python3 and pymodbus.

I found some instructions to compile the driver for Raspian, got it loaded and accepted.  However, when I run the same program as I did in Windows, I don't' get a result an get the below as a respone to a 'dmesg' command.

Does anyone know what this means, and if there's a clue there to try something?

Thanks

```
[  448.075850] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.0: xr_usb_serial_port_activate
[  448.076258] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.0: xr_usb_serial_ctrl_msg - rq 0x22,                                                     val 0x3, len 0x0, result 0
[  515.951828] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.0: xr_usb_serial_tty_close
[  515.951876] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.0: xr_usb_serial_port_shutdown
[  515.952299] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.0: xr_usb_serial_ctrl_msg - rq 0x22,                                                     val 0x0, len 0x0, result 0
[  515.952339] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.0: xr_usb_serial_ctrl_irq - urb shutt                                                    ing down with status: -2
[  515.952375] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952417] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952450] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952478] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952506] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952534] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952612] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952649] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952730] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952769] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952806] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952883] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.952922] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.953000] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.953037] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.953115] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.1: xr_usb_serial_read_bulk_callback -                                                     non-zero urb status: -2
[  515.953307] cdc_xr_usb_serial 1-1.3.1:1.0: xr_usb_serial_tty_cleanup
```

Comment: Did you apply for root permission to the usb-serial port like that: `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0`?

Comment: Early on, yes, I did try that.  I also checked the group  membership, which in this case is "dialup" of which my user is a member.

Comment: I just came across this http://ioninja.com/, and in thinking that it might help troubleshoot the bus. Has anyone had any success with this tool? Can it work like a "soft" sniffer in that it can catch everything going over an arbitrary port without extra hardware wiring?